# exponential inequality via calculus

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

I am wondering if an inequality such as
$$
\exp(x+y)\leq \exp(x) + \exp(y)
$$
for certain values of $x$ and $y$. According to wolfram alpha, it should hold for the region $\mathcal{R}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon x\leq0,y\leq 0 \}$ which for me works. My calculus is a bit rusty, but what I tried is defining the function $f(x,y)=\exp(x+y)- \exp(x) - \exp(y)$ and try to minimise/maximise it. The gradient $\nabla f(x,y)$ vanishes just at $(0,0)$, and the determinant of the Hessian matrix is negative at this point, so this is a saddle point, which makes sense since according to WA the reverse inequality holds in the complement of the region $\mathcal{R}$. How can I search for the maximum of $f$ in the desired region?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I have the feeling that I should be able to say something even stronger, but with this it would suffice.

Comment: try $x=1,y=2$ and your inequality is wrong

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner but those points do not belong to the desired region.

Comment: It is more likely you have opposite direction for enough large $x,y >0$ !!

Comment: Notice that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$, so you want to determine when $\exp(x)\exp(y)\leq \exp(x)+\exp(y)$. So when are added positive numbers smaller than multiplied positive numbers?

Comment: There is no maximum of $f$ in ${\cal R}$, but one has $\sup_{(x,y)\in{\cal R}}f(x,y)=0$, which is approximated when $x\to-\infty$, $y\to-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and $x\leq 0$ then $0<\exp(y)$ and $0<\exp(x)\leq 1$ which imply that
$$\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\cdot \exp(y)\leq \exp(y) \leq \exp(x)+\exp(y).$$
By symmetry the same holds when  $y\leq 0$.

P.S. If $x>0$ then it is easy to verify that $\exp(x+y)\leq \exp(x)+\exp(y)$ holds if and only if 
$$y\leq x-\ln(\exp(x)-1).$$
Take a look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x-ln(exp(x)-1)%3E%3Dy).

Comment: @Felipe Pérez You can find a stronger statement in my P.S.